# Conda environment from .yml file

Tags: python, conda

I exported my conda environment to `.yml` file using

```
conda env export > "myEnvironment.yml"
```

Then I tried to install it using

```
conda env create --prefix C:\Path\To\MyEnv --file "myEnvironment.yml"
```

Unfortunately, I got the error "An unexpected error has occurred.". The interesting thing is that when I copied the content of "myEnvironment.yml" file to some old '.yml' file which I created from my old environment some time ago, then it works! What can be the reason?

Comment: Maybe you're yaml file got malformed somehow, such as hidden chars

Comment: Copying the content and saving it again as yml file also help. The question is why the file produced by console doesn't work because it's quite annoying

Comment: To complement @Chris_Rands, what about opening the YAML with a text editor and check newlines and other hidden characters, or even perhaps encodings.

Comment: …or better yet, try comparing YAML files with some diff tool and see what's the difference.  It's likely newlines, as guys above had suggested.

Comment: Close voting as unreproducible. If you would like to make this question useful, create a minimal example and document how it fails exactly - e.g., include actual shell commands and results. Another useful output would be running the failing command with verbosity turned up.